# Checking styles before changing?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a menu and I'm showing some content only if the user is on the home page. This condition runs every time any menu item is clicked. If the user clicks on the other menu items I do not want to display this content. I'm trying to prevent the JavaScript from having to go back and forth from the HTML. Is this excessive?

Example:

```
if(pageNumber === home) {
    $('#content').css({'display':'block'});
} else if($('#content').css('display') !== 'none') {
    $('#content').css({'display':'none'});
}
```

Comment: Can you just bind a click event on the home menu button? Do you have some sort of differentiation between the home button and the other navigation links?

Comment: Should be posted as comment

Comment: I already have an event binded to the element. I'd prefer to keep this as simple as possible and prevent multiple events binding to an element...if that's possible even possible.

Comment: @JustinBoyd I wasn't suggesting to have multiple bind events to one element. I was suggesting to bind a event handler for that specific home-page menu item. Can you show how you are creating your menus.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just use the `toggle` method:

```
$('#content').toggle(pageNumber === home);
```

http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

Comment: Good suggestions, I didn't realize you could pass toggle with a true/false condition. I am curious though...does running a style check go into the html to get that value? or is it stored in the document.getElementById?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you asking, are you concerned about performance?

Comment: Correct, my question is about performance. I believe I found an answer here:http://jsperf.com/speed-difference-of-toggling-of-visibility-jquery-vs-pu

Ultimately, I wanted to find out if it is excessive to check a style before you set a style.

Comment: In most cases it will be excessive unless the style you are applying is very expensive (like gradients). In general the majority of the cost will be looking up the element and wrapping it as a jQuery object, and you'll have to do that if you are checking if a style exists.